# C# remove duplicates from jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, duplicates

I am writing an algorithm for university. And I have almost everything except the last thing.
I now have jagged array of numbers, example of this array:

```
[0][1]
[1][11,12]
[2][3,7,11,15]
[3][6,7,10,11]
```

And i need to remove duplicates, like delete every number from all next rows, that is present in the previos row.
Output should be something like this:

```
[0][1]
[1][11,12]
[2][3,7,15]
[3][6,10]
```

I have tried something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numbers.Length + 1; i++)
{
    int size = numbers[i].Length;
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        if (numbers[i][numbers[i].Length] != numbers[i + 1][numbers[i + 1].Length])
        {
            newNumbers[i][j] = numbers[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not work the way it should.

Comment: Is `[0] [1] [2] [3]` part of array, or just indexes?

Comment: Why are you comparing lengths in your if statement ?

Comment: It's the if statement and the contents within if statement that is causing issue. Make sure you make correct use of i and j variable to manipulate array.

Comment: You may need to have a secondary data structure (such as a dictionary) which stores the duplicate number and it’s locations. Your first pass of the array populates this dictionary- the second pass uses this information to remove duplicates

Comment: Pavel Anikhouski they are indexes.

Comment: auburg Cause I thought I need to have this value different for the statement before " != " and after this. And I am not sure how do i achive this. I thougth that I was doing this right, but now when you mentioned this, I see its wrong. I know it hase to be j  for the first one, and for the second one it should be j after this loop is done. And for your second comment, I will try to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve it by using [`Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.8) method from `System.Linq` namespace.

At every loop iteration go through all next rows and get the difference between these rows and current one and reassign it back. It's possible, because [jagged array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) is an array whose elements are arrays and you have the same `int` data type for all items

```cs
int[][] jaggedArray = new int[4][];

jaggedArray[0] = new[] { 1 };
jaggedArray[1] = new[] { 11, 12 };
jaggedArray[2] = new[] { 3, 7, 11, 15 };
jaggedArray[3] = new[] { 6, 7, 10, 11 };

for (int i = 0; i < jaggedArray.Length; i++)
{
    var currentRow = jaggedArray[i];
    for (int j = i + 1; j < jaggedArray.Length; j++)
    {
        var result = jaggedArray[j].Except(currentRow);
        jaggedArray[j] = result.ToArray();
    }
}
```

If you print the result array

```cs
foreach (var array in jaggedArray)
{
    foreach (var item in array) 
        Console.Write($"{item} ");

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The output will be the following

[image: result]

Comment: Would that work if there’s duplicate numbers in non adjacent  rows?

Comment: OP mentioned that _delete every number from all next rows, that is present in the previos row._ The internal `for` loop go through all next rows until end of array, at every iteration of main loop

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski it's working, thank you very much. You just saved me from sitting next few hours and trying to achive this.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int[][] RemoveDuplicates(this int[][] data)
{
    var result = new int[data.Length][];
    var used = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        var hashSet = new HashSet<int>(data[i].Except(used));
        result[i] = hashSet.ToArray();
        used.AddRange(hashSet);
    }
    return result;
}
```